# JavaScript procedure to find the characters that are in one string but not in another

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'e been trying to write one and it's getting messy!

Suppose I have two strings `textStart`, `textTarget` and I want to keep track of the characters I would need to add and remove from `textStart` in order to product `textTarget`.

For instance, if `textStart` = `"dude"` and `textTarget` = `"deck"`, then characters that would need to be added would be `'c'` and `'k'` and the characters that would need to be substracted would be the `'u'` and one of the `'d'`s.

I'm thinking that I first need to create maps that represent the number of each character in `textStart` and `textTarget`.

So I wrote this:

```
    var startChars = {};
    for (var k = 0, n = textStart.length; k < n; ++k)
    {
        if (textStart[k] in startChars)
            ++startChars[textStart[k]];
        else
            startChars[textStart[k]] = 1;
    }
    var targetChars = {};
    for (var k = 0, n = textTarget.length; k < n; ++k)
    {
        if (textTarget[k] in startChars)
            ++targetChars[textTarget[k]];
        else
            map1[targetChars[k]] = 1;
    }
```

Which would give me

`startChars['d']`=`2`,
`startChars['u']`=`1`,
`startChars['e']`=`1`

and

`targetChars['d']`=`1`,
`targetChars['e']`=`1`,
`targetChars['c']`=`1`,
`targetChars['k']`=`1`

Then I can make create maps `needAdded` and `needRemoved` that look at the difference in the above two maps:

```
    var needAdded = {}; 
    var needRemoved = {};
```

I'm not sure how to fill those maps as intended, because I don't know how to iterate through the keys of a map using JavaScript. I somehow need to end up with

`needAdded['c']`=`1`,
`needAdded['k']`=`1`,
`needRemoved['u']`=`1`,
`needRemoved['d']`=`1`

That's where you guys come in and help me.

I hope I've done a good job describing what I'm trying to do and how I've tried to do it so far. My programming intuition tells me that I'm writing too many lines of code and that I need to consult StackOverflow for help. Any way to do this elegantly without JQuery or Regex? I know someone's going to come in this thread and write a 1-line Regex solution or something like that.

Comment: to loop through objects use the `for(var key in object){}`

Comment: What do you have against regex? Not that I think it's useful here.

Comment: In terms of "too much code" you can refactor your loop to build your map into a function so you only need to write it once. Then use `for...in` as @A.O. suggested (also you could stick that in a function since you'll need to loop over properties in both objects).

Comment: @MattBurland I thought that it was considered bad programming to create a new function for a procedure you were only going to use twice anyways

Comment: @user3461018 - No, no, not at all. Code re-use is just *one* of the reason to extract related code into a function. It's also useful for readability, organization, and I've often found that the act of forcing myself to give some code a name greatly helps me understand what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: @user3461018: No. If you are using more than once, that's exactly when you create a function. Even if you are only using it once, sometimes it makes sense to make it a function for the purposes of organizing the code better and making it more readable and easier to maintain and reason about. Plus those "only need it once" functions have a habit of become "used all other the place" functions.

Comment: I've come to believe over the years that the single most important reason to create a function is to give a group of code *some name*. If you can't think of a simple, concise name, then you either don't really know what the hell it's doing, or it's trying to do way too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = 'dude',
t = 'deck',
finalOutput = '';
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    if ( typeof t[i] != 'undefined' ){
        if ( s[i] != t[i] ){
            console.log(s[i] + ' changed to ' + t[i]);
            s[i] = t[i];
            finalOutput += t[i];

        } else{
            finalOutput += s[i];
        }
    }
}
console.log('FINAL: ' + finalOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bpcB/) I just spent way too much time on... hopefully it makes sense :)

```
var textStart = 'dude';
var textTarget = 'deck';

var startChars = {};
for (var k = 0, n = textStart.length; k < n; ++k)
{
    if (textStart[k] in startChars)
        ++startChars[textStart[k]];
    else
        startChars[textStart[k]] = 1;
}

var targetChars = {};
for (var k = 0, n = textTarget.length; k < n; ++k)
{
    if (textTarget[k] in targetChars)
        ++targetChars[textTarget[k]];
    else
        targetChars[textTarget[k]] = 1;
}

console.log('start: ' + JSON.stringify(startChars));
console.log('target: ' + JSON.stringify(targetChars));

var needAdded = {};
var needRemoved = {};

for (var c in startChars) {
    // If target does not contain letter, remove all, otherwise remove excess
    if (targetChars[c] > 0) {
        if (startChars[c] > targetChars[c])
            needRemoved[c] = startChars[c] - targetChars[c];
        else if (startChars[c] < targetChars[c])
            needAdded[c] = targetChars[c] - startChars[c];
    } else {
        needRemoved[c] = startChars[c];
    }
}

for (var c in targetChars) {
    // If start does not contain letter, add all, otherwise add excess
    if (startChars[c] > 0) {
        if (startChars[c] > targetChars[c])
            needRemoved[c] = startChars[c] - targetChars[c];
        else if (startChars[c] < targetChars[c])
            needAdded[c] = targetChars[c] - startChars[c];
    } else {
        needAdded[c] = targetChars[c];
    }
}

console.log('needAdded: ' + JSON.stringify(needAdded));
console.log('needRemoved: ' + JSON.stringify(needRemoved));
```

The output is as follows:

```
start: {"d":2,"u":1,"e":1}
target: {"d":1,"e":1,"c":1,"k":1}
needAdded: {"c":1,"k":1}
needRemoved: {"d":1,"u":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, also too much time on this:

```
var textStart = "dude";
var textTarget = "duck";

var map = {};
MapCharacters(textStart, map, 1);
MapCharacters(textTarget, map, -1);
console.log(map);

var toDelete = [];
var toAdd = [];

for (var prop in map) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        while (map[prop] > 0) {
            toDelete.push(prop);
            map[prop]--;
        }
        while (map[prop] < 0) {
            toAdd.push(prop);
            map[prop]++;
        }

    }
}

console.log(toDelete);
console.log(toAdd);

function MapCharacters(string, map, add) {
    for (var k = 0, n = string.length; k < n; ++k) {
        if (string[k] in map) {
            map[string[k]] += add;
        } else {
            map[string[k]] = add;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nSV2J/1/

It could probably be done more efficiently, but as I said - too much time!

I realized that the best way to do this is not to make two maps, but just one. In the first case you increment the count for each letter and in the second case you decrease it. Now it's easy to find which ones need to be removed (the ones that end up > 0) and which ones need to be added (the ones that end up < 0)